# De donde salen los valores de las siguientes variables?

Tags: c, variables

Me podrían explicar como obtienen ese valor las variables x,y,z en este código:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    main(){

    float x=1, *y, z=3;
    y= &x;
    x=z+5;
    y++;

    printf("%f\n",x); /*8.000000*/
    printf("%f\n",y); /*8.000000*/
    printf("%f\n",z); /*3.000000*/
    printf("%f\n",&y); /*3.000000*/

    }
```

Comment: ¿Sabes lo que es un puntero? Si no, tendrías que aprenderlo antes para entender qué es la variable `y`. En todo caso,  el hecho de que al imprimir `y` salga `8.0000` es una casualidad asombrosa... (y que `&y`salga `3.00000`). Intentaré investigar por qué ocurre eso, si es que esa era tu pregunta...

Comment: Entiendo el funcionamiento de los punteros, pero no encuentro el sentido a los valores que me da al ejecutarlo en c

Comment: `printf("%f\n",y);` es imposible que muestre `8`, porque `y` es un puntero ¿querías decir `printf("%f\n",*y);`?

Answer (score 3):

He verificado que a mi me sale lo mismo. Voy a intentar explicar lo que yo creo que debería salir, y una posible conjetura de por qué no sale eso.

```
float x=1, *y, z=3;
y= &x;
x=z+5;
y++;
```

La variable `x` está clara. Toma el valor 1 inicialmente, pero luego le cambias el valor cuando haces `x=z+5`, por lo que termina con el valor 8.0. No hay sorpresas en esa.

La variable `y` es de tipo puntero. Al hacerle `y=&x` le estás asignando la dirección de memoria de la variable `x`. Las direcciones de memoria son en el fondo números, de 32 bits o de 64 bits, según la arquitectura de la CPU y del operativo.

Digamos que son de 64 bits. Entonces la variable `x` podría estar almacenada por ejemplo en la dirección de memoria `00007ffffa19b704`, y al hacer `y=&x`, estás asignándole a `y` el valor `00007ffffa19b704`. Estos números no son inventados. Son los que me han salido al ejecutarlo en Linux.

Cuando imprimes `y` en el segundo `printf()` el compilador debería darte un *warning* ya que estás especificando `%f` como cadena de formato, por lo que espera una variable de tipo float, pero encuentra en cambio `y`, que es de tipo `float*`. Aún así "traga". Cuando llega el momento de ejecutar esa llamada, `printf()` recibirá el número `00007ffffa19b704` en binario, e intentará decodificarlo según el estándar IEEE754 de punto flotante de simple precisión.

Para empezar tenemos un problema, porque según ese estándar lo que espera son 32 bits, y está recibiendo 64. Posiblemente interpretará sólo la parte baja de ese dato, es decir `fa19b704`. Pero es que decodificando ese número (por ejemplo [usando esto](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) sale que el número representado es `-1.9953335E35` y no 8.00000. Primer WTF?

A continuación imprimes `z`. Aquí tampoco hay sorpresas, puesto que `z` es un `float` al que asignaste al principio el valor `3.0`, y eso es justamente lo que sale.

Finalmente imprimes `&y`. De nuevo estamos haciendo algo mal, ya que `&y` no es un `float` sino la dirección de un puntero a float, es decir, un  `float**`. Pero poco importa que sea un `float*` o un `float**`. Lo importante es que es (otra vez) una dirección de memoria. En este caso una dirección diferente, ya que es la dirección donde está guardada la variable `y`. Digamos que es `00007ffffa19b708`.

Cabe decir lo mismo de antes. Al intentar imprimir ese dato como si fuera float, posiblemente se quede sólo con su parte baja (`fa19b708`) y lo decodifique como un flotante IEEE754. Pero debería dar `-1.9953343E35` y no `3.0`. Segundo WTF?

### Mi conjetura

Opino que, puesto que lo que le estamos dando a `printf()` en el segundo y cuarto caso son datos "rotos" (direcciones de memoria en lugar de flotantes), si esas direcciones <strike>dan como resultado al decodificarse un error de punto flotante (un número no válido, fuera de rango, infinito, o NaN), posiblemente `printf()` "rompa" e imprima  cualquier cosa</strike>. (Ya no opino esto, ver actualización)

Mi hipótesis es que devuelve lo que tenía en una variable local sobre la que va construyendo el string resultante. Y que esa variable es estática y por tanto contiene el resultado de la ejecución anterior. Y que por tanto imprime lo mismo que había impreso el `printf()` anterior.

### Mi prueba de concepto

Para verificar si mi conjetura es correcta, ejecuté el siguiente programa:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
main(){

    float x=1, *y;
    y= &x;

    printf("%f\n",M_PI);
    printf("%f\n",y);

}
```

Resultado:

```
3.141593
3.141593
```

Lo que corrobora mi hipótesis. Ahora sólo queda por dilucidar por qué la dirección de `x` no es un número IEEE754 válido :-)

### Actualización

Aunque la "prueba de concepto" sigue apuntando en la dirección de que `printf()` está mostrando el buffer de una conversión previa, las razones de que haga esto están menos claras. Inicialmente pensé que podía deberse a un bug en la implementación de `printf_fp` (la función de la libc que se ocupa de dar formato a números de punto flotante), que se comportaba mal ante ciertos números. Pero no es esta la causa.

El siguiente programa copia *esos mismos números* que causaban problemas (es decir, una copia del valor del puntero) a otra variable, esta vez de tipo `double`, y `printf()` la muestra sin problemas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){
    double x=8.0, *y;
    double zz;
    y= &x;

    printf("%g\n", 3.14);
    printf("%g\n", y);
    memcpy(&zz, &y, sizeof(y));
    printf("%g\n", zz);
}
```

Salida:

```
3.14
3.14
6.95285e-310
```

Por tanto la causa del misterio no está en los bytes que `printf()` recibe en la variable, sino en el tipo de esta variable. De algún modo el que sea un puntero en lugar de un `float` marca una diferencia en lo que `printf_fp()` recibe. A partir de ahi tenemos comportamiento indefinido (aunque muy consistente).

Comment: No termino de estar seguro de si darte +1 ... el ejemplo del OP no es válido en Windows (gcc 6.4), pero en Linux si. Pero POSIX dice que `printf( )` es *thread-safe*, o sea que no usa variables `static` ni similares ... es un caso muy muy curioso O_o

Comment: @Trauma Que conste que me he mirado el código fuente de printf en la stdlib, pero es demasiado farragoso, pues delega en vprintf y éste a su vez en printf_fp para el caso `float`, y no hay quién entienda nada...

Comment: ¡ *Otia* ! Aclarado pues. +1. Solo por el intento de *meterle mano* al código de `stdlib` xD

Comment: @Trauma y tampoco acaba de convencerme a mí mi "explicación" de que el valor del puntero no pueda ser decodificado como un IEEE754 válido, pues no he sido capaz a dar con una combinación de los bytes en `00007ffffa19b704` (teniendo en cuenta diferentes _endianities_) que diera un número inválido. Pienso ahora si no tendrá algo qué ver más bien el código generado por `gcc` en la llamada, pues da un _warning_ de que los tipos no coinciden. Igual se "pasa de listo" y no le está pasando el valor del puntero... tengo que investigarlo

Comment: En Windows, probé con usar varias optimizaciones (incluso `-O0`)por si acaso, que ya me ha hecho alguna cosa rara antes. Pero no, el comportamiento indicado no se reproduce. Incluso pensé en que sería cosa de la ABI (en amd64 pasa 16bytes mínimo) ... pero la verdad es que no llego a tan bajo nivel. Ahí lo dejé.

Comment: Utilizando otros compiladores más antiguos de 32 bits, la variable `y` no mostraba ningún valor.

Comment: ¿Cómo puede darte lo mismo que a user105251? Su código es incorrecto: `printf("%f\n",y);` es imposible que muestre `8` y `printf("%f\n",&y);` es imposible que muestre `3`.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus Ahi está todo el misterio... Esas llamadas disparan un _warning_, pero igualmente sale un ejecutable. Y al ejecutarlo sale 8.0 y 3.0 (en linux, 64bits). La cuestión es ¿de dónde saca printf esos valores?

Comment: No tiene ni pies ni cabeza. Muy posiblemente sea comportamiento indefinido.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus Sí, indefinido pero muy consistente. En todo caso no tiene pies ni cabeza, efectivamente. Lo que quería encontrar (aunque ya me he rendido) es la razón por la cual `printf()` parece estar mostrando un resultado previo, cuando en teoría no debe tener variables estáticas por ser _thread safe_. Por cierto, mira la actualización que acabo de añadir

Comment: Indefinido no significa no determinístico, significa indefinido xD

Answer (score 0):

la variable *y es una Desreferencia.
mientras que &y es referencia.
creo que esto te podria ayudar a entenderlo mejor...
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Operadores_de_C_y_C%2B%2B

Comment: `*y` es "contenido de `y`", usa el operador de des-referencia. `&y` no es referencia, es "dirección de `y`*".